# graphql-ruby, rails generate graphql:install doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, graphql

When I run `rails generate graphql:install`, it throws errors, even I already gem install graphql and graphql-relay.

These are the error messages.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 64355
Expected boolean default value for '--markerb'; got :erb (string)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Could not find generator 'graphql:install'. Maybe you meant 'react:install', 'pundit:install' or 'devise:install'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

Rails -v 4.2.5
Ruby -v 2.4.0

[gem link](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby)

Comment: you sure you've `gem "graphql" ` in your gemfile ?

Comment: @ChiragArya yes, gem "graphql" is in my gemfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like these two gems are not compatible with each other. Please follow these steps to overcome this issue.

1. Remove `gem 'graphql-relay'` from your `Gemfile`.
2. `bundle install`
3. Make sure you have latest version of `graphql`

   - Check your `Gemfile.lock` latest graphql version is 1.5.2
4. execute generator `rails generate graphql:install`

Cheers